# how to implement code for display array list elements as one records and how to set different color for each record?

Tags: android, android-layout

hi all  i am getting three types of array list information storing in one array list but here i have to display first array list fist element second array list first element and third array list first element display as one record and first array of second  element second array of second second element and third array second element display as one record like this third etc... and also how to set color for each record in different color( i mean first record red color, second record in yellow color and third record in green color) so how to implement code for  solve this problem. help me any one of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link of custom listview.

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html